# How to create object by parsing a Map to constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

In Dart, is it possible to create an object by parsing a map to constructor?

*Example:*

```
class User {
 final String? id;
 final String? name;
 
 User({this.id, this.name});
}


// Using a map to initiate a `User` object, how to achieve similar functionality?
final map = {'id': '1323', 'name': 'foo'};
User foo = User(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By creating a factory:

```
  factory MyUser.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>? map) {

    if(map == null){
      return MyUser( id: "", nom: "", imageUrl: '');
    }


    return MyUser(
      id: map['id'] as String,
      imageUrl: map['imageUrl'] as String? ?? '',
      nom: map['nom'] as String,
    );
  }
```